# How to stop npm build when ESLint has warnings?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, eslint

While dealing with a very immature team, I want the react-typescript build to fail when ESLint gives warnings.

```
src/modules/security/components/ForgotPasswordBox/index.tsx
  Line 8:18:  'FormikHelpers' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

src/modules/security/components/OTPVerificationBox/modalverficationcode.tsx
  Line 54:18:  Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='  eqeqeq
  Line 63:29:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq
```

But on the net I only find the reverse where people would want to turn off warnings or build to continue even with warnings which is the exact opposite of what I'm looking for.

I do not use build pipeline or any such thing. We have a react -typescript app with NPM as package manager.

```
 "scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"lint": "eslint . --max-warnings=0"
},

  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
```

kindly let me know how can I achieve this behavior?. Please note that typescript compiler settings strict is already set to true.

Comment: Then configure eslint to be stricter. Let it throw errors instead of warnings.

Comment: Can you share what the build script is set to? Want to confirm what you're using to compile.

Comment: Possibly related: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict

Comment: @JBallin I just did. tell me what needs to be done

Comment: Ah you're using CRA with the typescript template I'm guessing

Comment: @JBallin  no idea what you are talking about. if you kindly let me know the steps I have to perform or if you need any more info let me know

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/

Comment: Can you try setting strict to true in your tsconfig?

Comment: it is on already

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248871/discussion-between-simple-fellow-and-jballin).

Comment: @SimpleFellow see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your `build` script fail, you can either update your CI to run `npm run lint && npm run build` or create a new script to use in your CI (e.g. `"production": "npm run lint && npm run build"`).

This way the CI build will fail on the `lint` script before even starting the `build` script. This exposes the logic, instead of hiding it within the `build` script.

---

In the future you could consider running these in parallel and cause either one failing to fail the CI build and/or require a passing GitHub status check (based on success/fail of each script).

Comment: It's worth noting that in case of ESLint or Next Lint, you should add `--max-warnings 0` option to the script definition in `package.json` file.